# select similar value from MySQL and order the result

Tags: php, mysql

how do I order this result??

```
$range = 5;  // you'll be selecting around this range. 
$min = $rank - $range;
$max = $rank + $range;
$limit = 10; // max number of results you want. 

$result = mysql_query("select * from table where rank between $min and $max limit $limit");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $row['name']."&nbsp;-&nbsp;".$row['rank']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: please, format your code using the "101010"-Icon.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be ORDER BY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "order by"- clause:

```
mysql_query("select * from table where rank between $min and $max order by rank limit $limit");
```

This will order your result from little to big values. 
Use `"order by rank desc"` to order in descendent direction. (big -> little)

Comment: thanks but how can I display search query in middle and rest is above and below example:
seach is mathew
and the result should be display below:-

john - 26
joe - 25
stewart - 27
mathew - 25
kelly - 24
brandon -23
magy - 22 .......etc.

Comment: Use 2 select clauses: The one looking for values between "rank - range" and "rank" and the other looking for values between "rank + 1" and "rank + range". Order the first in ascending and the second in descending order.

Comment: OOps my bad i got the answer. actually it is more easier than that.
only thing needs to do is 
"select * from table where rank between $min and $max order by rank desc limit $limit"
thats it...

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "select * from table where rank between $min and $max " . 
    "order by rank asc limit $limit"
);
```